# Unable to set offset value for last item of carousel?

Tags: ios, iphone, icarousel

[image]I am using iCarousel in my application to show images which is coming from web service with linear type carousel. When user scroll end of the carousel if no images available from web service i am adding one carousel with button.
What i am doing is when no data available from web service i am setting boolean value yes(isNoImagesAvailable == YES).then i am adding one extra carousel item on bottom.

Below is example  code to understand how i am doing

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {

        self.carousel.contentOffset = CGSizeMake(0, (213 - self.carousel.frame.size.height) * 0.5);

    }
    else
    {
        self.carousel.contentOffset = CGSizeMake(0, (200 - self.carousel.frame.size.height) * 0.5);
    }

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{

 //Here i am increasing carousel count by 1 if no images available
    if (isNoImagesAvailable)
    {

        return images.count+1;
    }
    else
    {
    return images.count;
    }
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling

  if(index < images.count  )
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        //this `if (view == nil) 
{`        
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image =// Here loading images from web service
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    }
    else


    return view;
}
// if no images are available adding one button with text "No data available" 
else
    {
        UIView * endimageView = nil;
            if (view == nil)
            {
                endimageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150.0f,50.0f)];
                endimageView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
                endimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
                UIButton *noDataButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                noDataButton.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40);
                noDataButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                [noDataButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [noDataButton setTitle:@"No data available" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [noDataButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popToHomePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                noDataButton.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
                [endingDealView addSubview: noDataButton s];


            }

        return endingDealView;

    }
```

Here the problem is when user on bottom of the screen when scroll up "No data available" button is going below the navigation bar. How can make "endimageView" carousel item offset to exact below the navigation bar.

Let me know any information need from my side
 Thanks

Comment: can u provide a screen shot of these issue

Comment: @Suhail one minute i am sending screen shot

Comment: i updated question with screen shot

Comment: or can i make atleast two items visable when we at last item